# Angular blog-like architecture, view caching

Tags: angularjs

So let’s say I have one-page-application which is something like a blog: there is an index page with route `site.com/` where all the posts are listed and a "post view" page with route `site.com/post/:post_id`. All data loads asynchronously.

Right now everything is relied on one `ng-view` and router is set up like this:

```
$routeProvider.
  when('/', {
    templateUrl: '/partials/index.html',
    controller: 'Index'
  }).
  when('/post/:post_id', {
    templateUrl: '/partials/post.html',
    controller: 'Post'
  })
```

Obviously, when switching between index page and post page, views are removed from the DOM and controllers are reloaded.

What is the best way to achieve caching of an Index view, so that it won't be rerendered every time I switch from post back to index page? I cache server response data using a service, so it is the rerendering that worries me.

Comment: Have a look at $templateCache. It might be what you are looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't worry about the re-rendering... this is going to be quick.  Let Angular worry about that. As for fetching and caching your templates, I can think of two ways you can do this that will avoid the Ajax calls for templates:

1. Put your templates on the page in the form of `<script>` tags:

   ```
   <script type="text/ng-template" id="/partials/index.html">
      Your template here
   </script>

   <script type="text/ng-template" id="/partials/post.html">
       Another template here
   </script>
   ```

   Angular will load these templates in to the `$templateCache`. If you are using a server side technology like ASP.NET MVC, Ruby on Rails, Grails, or similar, it is simple to create partial views in those technologies which will include your templates.
2. If you don't like putting `<script>` tags on the page, you can have a "build" step compile your templates and place them in the template cache. The result will be one giant JavaScript file which contains all of your templates in JavaScript form.

   There is a GruntJS plug-in which will do this for you for your Angular templates. I believe it essentially builds a module which will load all templates in to the `$templateCache`. This can be found here: https://github.com/karlgoldstein/grunt-html2js